# nodejs thread usage with variables quest

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, nodes

I'm new here and I created my account today just to ask this

I'm studying nodejs and getting trouble with threads.

```
var spawn = require("threads").spawn;

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
var threads = spawn(function(i){
    console.log(i)
});
```

}

all I want to do is print the thread execution order, but var i is not defined inside spawn function, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library is built on top Web Workers

A worker runs in a different javascript file that contains the code that will run in the worker thread, they have a different global context from the current window. you cannot refer to the outer scope environment as you usually do in javascript.

```
const spawn = require('threads').spawn;
const thread = spawn(function(input, done) {
  // Everything we do here will be run in parallel in another execution context. 
  // Remember that this function will be executed in the thread's context, 
  // so you cannot reference any value of the surrounding code. 
  done({ string : input.string, integer : parseInt(input.string) });
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads

Comment: I saw that, but this doesn't help me, while using for to create multiple threads, the variables get lost

Comment: i've fixed my answer. this is the how web workers are implemented. you cannot refer to the outer scope.